# angular 5 ngModel conditional binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

i'm working in angular 5 , and i have some problems .
I have two models Person, and Employee that inherit from Person and have its own attributes. in html file of my component i created a form with some input fields :

```
<input type="texte" name="name" [(ngModel)]="person.name" />
<input type="texte" name="numberPhone" [(ngModel)]="person.numberPhone" />
<button (click)="isEmployee=true" type="button">is employee</button>
<div *ngIf="isEmployee">
<input type="texte" name="salary" [(ngModel)]="employee.salary" />
</div>
```

the problem is that i want to use the same form to bind person if isEmployee was false or employee if isEmployee was true. the follow code doesn't work

```
[(ngMode)]="isEmployee ? person.name : employee.name"
[(ngMode)]="isEmployee ? person.numberPhone : employee.numberPhone "
```

there is any way to do this without repeat the html code ?

Comment: Why don't you store it in the same `person` variable? You can use a type guard to distinguish between the types when needing to do things on the `Employee` type http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create one template with a ngModel that binds like it normally would:

```
[(ngMode)]="user.name"
```

and share this template file among different components for each type of user you have (so only the person component would have the template file) -- so in your case 1 component for person and one for employee. And in their respective components you can set user to employee in the employee component and person in the person component.